# Google Analytics (not set) - all pages

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have content grouping running on my webpage, the code is the next one:

1. google analytics script
2. onloadevent function with this code:

   ```
   var scatcms = $('ul.breadcrumb li:nth-child(2) a').text();
   ga('set', 'contentGroup1', scatcms);
   ```

Now, this code is on the `<head>` of every page.
When I go to analytics, I can see various categories, like "Mundo", "Lifestyle", ....

There is also a **(not set)**, and this should contain, for example, the homepage, but what is happening is that it contains all the pages.

---

example:

Category - Mundo // Sessions - 1

Category - Lifestyle // Sessions - 2

Category - (not set) // Sessions - 10,427 ---> in this number there is pages from Mundo category, or lifestyle category, why don't they show up on their category?

Comment: Check if the "set" call for the content groups is executed before the call to the pageview. This needs to be send along with the user interaction, and since your code seemingly relies on the DOM being rendered it might be you execute your pageview before you set the contentgroup.