# Google analytics 'not set' value as browser version?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular, google-analytics

Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34873007/google-analytics-not-set-all-pages), but my case is different.

I have added google analytics script to my project(angular4) and I am getting all information except for browser information.
I can see 'not set' value as some of the browsers and I found that there some tips to remove it, but that seems like we need to add some filter to exclude these data.
Is there any solution to print actual information instead of 'not set' value.

Thanks in advance.'

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(not set)` means just that the information was not set.  So Google analytics can not tell you what browser it was.

**Possible cause and fix**

When you visit a webpage, the page detects what is called a [user agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent). The user agent has information related to what device you are using as well as which browser and browser version. If you see `(not set)`, it is likely accounting for a very small percentage of your traffic. Google had libraries to identify user agents so when it does not match, `(not set)` will show up.

This could indicate crawlers and bots, especially if you see a bounce rate and new sessions percentage near 100% and an average session duration of less than a second.

Fix: Make sure the option to exclude hits from known bots and spiders is checked in your View Settings.

Read more about not set [here](https://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2015/06/25/11-places-google-analytics-not-set/)

Comment: As I understood google is considering these types data is from bots, right?

Comment: Yeah pretty much  or referral spam depends upon how you look at it guess.

Comment: this also happens when users land on your website after clicking on a link from a different app like instagram or facebook. 

these visits will show up as `safari (in-app)` `(web view or something like this for android users)` for browser and `not set` for the browser version.

unfortunately for us, about 65% of our users are iphone users who clicked on an instagram ad so i have no way of telling what version of safari they are using.